# Captive portal and walled internet

Tags: proxy, reverse-dns, captive-portal, wifi

I am creating a tour guide app which visitors can download when they arrive on location. There will be a Hotspot to which they connect, they will get a welcome page with instruction (and a button to logon/continue) and this should allow them to download the App from the relevant App Store and download any additional data from our own servers.

In searching for a solution I came across WifiDog and AuthPuppy which performs the first part very well (automatic logon screen etc.). However, I cannot see how to configure to allow only communication to the selected services. WifiDog uses IPTables with only IP addresses, but for CDN's this wouldn't work. I could manual add rules to IPTables but don't know if this is possible, maybe with reverse DNS?

Maybe another option is to use a transparent proxy? I can setup a proxy on one of my server, but I don't have much experience with that. Will a proxy work for the communication of e.g. the App Store or the Play Store?

Any help or suggestions are really appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to use a CDN?

Comment: Apple and Google use CDNs and I need to provide access to them